# SVG API: length of a single segment

Tags: javascript, svg

Is it possible to get the length of a single segment (from anchor to anchor) in an SVG path with the Javascript API?

Comment: May be possible with http://snapsvg.io/docs/ under the Snap.path.* namespace. (A lot of utility methods for path scraping)

Comment: You make a good point, Matt. If anyone's solved this problem, it's likely Dmitry Baranovskiy. I'll do some digging in his repos.

Comment: Why not just ask him directly :)

Comment: Do you mean only <path> or also line, polyline, etc? And how do you like to specify the anchors?

Answer (score 3):

I made some uncluttered version of Francis Hemsher solution. Here's the full source code:

```
function getSegmentLengths(path) {
  let segList = path.pathSegList;

  // temporary path for computing segments
  let lengthPath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'path');
  let lastLength = 0;
  let segLengths = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < segList.numberOfItems; i += 1) {
    let segObj = segList.getItem(i);
    lengthPath.pathSegList.appendItem(segObj);
    let currentLength = lengthPath.getTotalLength();
    let segmentLength = currentLength - lastLength;
    segLengths.push({
      currentLength,
      segmentLength,
      type: segObj.pathSegTypeAsLetter
    });
    lastLength = currentLength;
  }

  return segLengths;
}
```

**Important NOTE:** To make it fully working in current version of Chrome (60), you have to use [pathseg polyfill](https://github.com/progers/pathseg).

See my sample on [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/bez997/pen/dzJemZ?editors=1010).

Comment: Nice hack, but very memory inefficient to generate SVG elements all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Create a pseudo path from the path points and read its total Length as each segment is added. Then do the math for each segment length

Below is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Path Segment Length</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.svgDiscovery.com/bowser.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style='padding:10px;font-family:arial'>
<center>
<h4>Path Segment Length</h4>
(This example tested in: IE11/CH31/FF23)

<div style='width:90%;background-color:gainsboro;text-align:justify;padding:10px;border-radius:6px;'>
<center>SVG API: length of a single segment</center>
Create a pseudo path from the path points and read its total Length as each segment is added. Then do the math for each segment length
</div>
<div id="svgDiv" style='background-color:lightblue;width:400px;height:400px;'>
<svg id="mySVG" width="400" height="400">
<path id="myPath" fill="yellow" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M 144.99 81.411 Q 93.5233 122.822 165.695 164.233 Q 220.897 230.491 242.969 164.233 Q 294.436 122.822 222.264 81.411 Q 167.062 15.1534 144.99 81.411" />
<path id="lengthPath" fill="none" />
</svg>
</div>
SVG Path Segment Lengths:<div id=pathSegLengthDiv></div>
  <br />SVG Source:<br />
<textarea id=svgSourceValue style='font-size:110%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:200px'></textarea>
 <br />Javascript:<br />
<textarea id=jsValue style='border-radius:26px;font-size:110%;font-weight:bold;color:midnightblue;padding:16px;background-color:beige;border-width:0px;font-size:100%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:400px'></textarea>
</center>
<div id='browserDiv' style='padding:3px;position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;background-color:gainsboro;'></div>
<script id=myScript>
function pathSegLengths(path)
{
    var segList=path.pathSegList
    var segs=segList.numberOfItems
    var pathSegsLen=""
    var d=""
    for(var k=0;k<segs;k++)
    {
        var segObj=segList.getItem(k)
        d+=segObj.pathSegTypeAsLetter

        if(segObj.x2 && segObj.y2)
        {
            var x2 = segObj.x2
            var y2 = segObj.y2
            d+=x2+" "+y2+" "
        }
        if(segObj.x1 && segObj.y1)
        {
            var x1 = segObj.x1
            var y1 = segObj.y1
            d+=x1+" "+y1+" "
        }
        if(segObj.x && segObj.y )
        {
            var x = segObj.x
            var y = segObj.y
            d+=x+" "+y+" "
        }

        lengthPath.setAttribute("d",d)
        pathSegsLen+="Total Length @ segment "+ k+"="+lengthPath.getTotalLength()+"</br>"
    }

    pathSegLengthDiv.innerHTML=pathSegsLen
    svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
}

</script>
<script>
document.addEventListener("onload",init(),false)
function init()
{
    browserVersion()
    svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
    jsValue.value=myScript.text
    pathSegLengths(myPath)
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I like how you've shown how pathSegList can be used to get a hold of the segments! This JS could be much simpler for a general audience, in my opinion. But otherwise, you've showed me a way to start chipping away at my solution. Thanks, Francis!

Comment: This will not work with shorthand/smooth curveto (`S`/`s`) and shorthand/smooth quadratic Bézier (`T`/`t`), which require a previous command. Do it incrementally (for a+b+c+... : a, a+b, a+b+c, etc.) minus previous length