# Manual animation for each path command for an SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, css-animations, drawing, image-optimization

Is it possible to do the animation on the drawing attribute of an SVG manually (with a button) for **each [path command](https://devdocs.io/svg/attribute/d#path_commands)** instead of continuously?

```css
.path {stroke-dasharray: 1000;
       stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
       animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;}
@keyframes dash {from {stroke-dashoffset: 822;}
                 to   {stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
                 }
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="50 50 240 270">
  <path class="path" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" 
        d="M66.039,133.545c0,0-21-57,18-67s49-4,65,8 s30,41,53,27s66,4,58,32s-5,44,18,57s22,46,0,
           45s-54-40-68-16s-40,88-83,48s11-61-11-80s-79-7-70-41 C46.039,146.545,53.039,128.545,66.039,133.545z"/>
</svg>
```

That could help one merge two or more path commands and reduce the number of drawing path commands in an SVG.

Comment: Just throwing it out there: As a last resort, we could always read the svg file, parse the values and draw them as we like.

Comment: Be aware most animations draw path **segments** in parallel; ie. when you have **m** / **M** commands in a ``path``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get the length for each path segment, since you're animating/transitioning `stroke-dasharray/stroke-dashoffset` values.

Here's a simplified example using a path showing a perfect circle with a circumference of 100 (diameter=31,832 * π). The path consists of 4 segments that should have a segment length of 25 units.

The helper function to get all segments lengths is based on
[@bez997's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564905/svg-api-length-of-a-single-segment#answer-45793408)

```js
let svg = document.querySelector("svg");
let path = svg.querySelector(".path");
let pathLength = path.getTotalLength().toFixed(1) * 1;

/**
 * save segments' path lengths to array
 **/

let segments = getSegmentLengths(path);
let segmentJson = JSON.stringify(segments).replaceAll('"', "");

/**
* @bez997
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564905/svg-api-length-of-a-single-segment#answer-45793408
original pen: https://codepen.io/bez997/pen/dzJemZ?editors=1010
**/

function getSegmentLengths(path) {
  let segList = path.pathSegList;
  // temporary path for computing segments
  let lengthPath = document.createElementNS(
    "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
    "path"
  );
  let lastLength = 0;
  let segLengths = [];
  let segSteps = [];
  let segOffset = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < segList.numberOfItems; i += 1) {
    let segObj = segList.getItem(i);
    lengthPath.pathSegList.appendItem(segObj);
    // rounding numbers
    let currentLength = lengthPath.getTotalLength().toFixed(1) * 1;
    let segmentLength = (currentLength - lastLength).toFixed(1) * 1;

    // strip M and Z commands since, they don't have any length
    if (segmentLength) {
      lastLength = currentLength;
      segSteps.push({
        offset: i == 1 ? 0 : -(lastLength - segmentLength).toFixed(1) * 1,
        dash: segmentLength,
        currentLength: currentLength
      });
    }
  }
  return segSteps;
}

/**
 * change stroke dash attributes for animation
 **/
function strokeTo(path, pathLength, offset, dash) {
  let gap = pathLength - dash;
  path.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", offset);
  path.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", dash + " " + gap);
}

/**
 * create navigation for each segment
 **/
function getStrokeNav(svg, segments, singleSegment = true, label = "") {
  let strokeNav = label;
  let index = 0;
  segments.forEach(function (el, i) {
    index++;
    let thisOffset = el.offset;
    let thisDash = el.dash;

    if (!singleSegment) {
      thisOffset = 0;
      thisDash = el.currentLength;
    }
    strokeNav +=
      '<button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,' +
      pathLength +
      ", " +
      thisOffset +
      ", " +
      thisDash +
      ')">' +
      index +
      "</button>";
  });

  return strokeNav;
}

// nav html output
let strokeToNav =
  "<p>" +
  getStrokeNav(svg, segments, false, "Animate to stroke segment ") +
  "</p><p>" +
  getStrokeNav(svg, segments, true, "Animate single segment ") +
  "</p>";
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterBegin", strokeToNav);
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: calc( ( 25vw + 25vh )/ 2) ;
  width: 1em;
}

.path{
  transition:0.5s
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/progers/pathseg/a1072a7b/pathseg.js"></script>
<svg  id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
      viewBox="0 0 50 50" >
<path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#000"  d="
M40.916,25
c0,8.79-7.125,15.916-15.916,15.916
S9.084,33.79,9.084,25
S16.21,9.084,25,9.084
S40.916,16.21,40.916,25
z" />
</svg>
```

The expected segment array would be:

```
let segments = [
  {offset:0, dash:25, currentLength:25},
  {offset:-25, dash:25, currentLength:50},
  {offset:-50, dash:25, currentLength:75},
  {offset:-75, dash:25, currentLength:100}
];
```

By also saving an offset value, we can transition to a segment (including previous segments) but also animate a single segment.

```
stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="25 75"
```

Would show the first (bottom right) segment stroke.

Once you got all segments' you could store this data to an array or json statically. Since the length calculation creates a temporary DOM element – so you might experience some performance hit, depending on the svg's complexity.

```js
let svg = document.querySelector("svg");
let path = svg.querySelector(".path");
let pathLength = path.getTotalLength().toFixed(1) * 1;

/**
 * save segments' path lengths to array
 **/
let segments = [
  { offset: 0, dash: 78.6, currentLength: 78.6 },
  { offset: -78.6, dash: 68.8, currentLength: 147.4 },
  { offset: -147.4, dash: 65.1, currentLength: 212.5 },
  { offset: -212.5, dash: 81.9, currentLength: 294.4 },
  { offset: -294.4, dash: 66.3, currentLength: 360.7 },
  { offset: -360.7, dash: 61.4, currentLength: 422.1 },
  { offset: -422.1, dash: 76.5, currentLength: 498.6 },
  { offset: -498.6, dash: 116.9, currentLength: 615.5 },
  { offset: -615.5, dash: 89.3, currentLength: 704.8 },
  { offset: -704.8, dash: 90.2, currentLength: 795 },
  { offset: -795, dash: 26.6, currentLength: 821.6 }
];


/**
 * change stroke dash attributes for animation
 **/
function strokeTo(path, pathLength, offset, dash) {
  let gap = pathLength - dash;
  path.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", offset);
  path.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", dash + " " + gap);
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: calc( ( 50vw + 50vh )/ 2) ;
  width: 1em;
}

.path{
  transition:0.5s
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="50 50 240 270">
  <path class="path" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" 
        d="M66.039,133.545c0,0-21-57,18-67s49-4,65,8 s30,41,53,27s66,4,58,32s-5,44,18,57s22,46,0,
           45s-54-40-68-16s-40,88-83,48s11-61-11-80s-79-7-70-41 C46.039,146.545,53.039,128.545,66.039,133.545z"/>
</svg>

<p>Animate to stroke segment <button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, 0, 78.6)">1</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, 0, 147.4)">2</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, 0, 212.5)">3</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, 0, 294.4)">4</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, 0, 360.7)">5</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, 0, 422.1)">6</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, 0, 498.6)">7</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, 0, 615.5)">8</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, 0, 704.8)">9</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, 0, 795)">10</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, 0, 821.6)">11</button></p>

<p>Animate single segment <button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, 0, 78.6)">1</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -78.6, 68.8)">2</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -147.4, 65.1)">3</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -212.5, 81.9)">4</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -294.4, 66.3)">5</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -360.7, 61.4)">6</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -422.1, 76.5)">7</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -498.6, 116.9)">8</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -615.5, 89.3)">9</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -704.8, 90.2)">10</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -795, 26.6)">11</button></p>
```

As an alternative you might also store your segments in a svg data attribute - albeit data-attributes are still not valid by specs.
However, they shouldn't introduce rendering issues.

A benefit of this approach would be, your segment data could directly be saved in your svg markup/file while reducing your js file.

```js
let svg = document.querySelector("svg");
let path = svg.querySelector(".path");
let pathLength = path.getTotalLength().toFixed(1)*1;


/**
* change stroke dash attributes for animation
**/
function strokeTo(path, pathLength, offset, dash) {
  let gap = pathLength - dash;
  path.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", offset);
  path.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", dash + " " + gap);
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: calc( ( 50vw + 50vh )/ 2) ;
  width: 1em;
}

.path{
  transition:0.3s
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="50 50 240 270" data-segments='[{"offset":0,"dash":78.6,"currentLength":78.6},{"offset":-78.6,"dash":68.8,"currentLength":147.4},{"offset":-147.4,"dash":65.1,"currentLength":212.5},{"offset":-212.5,"dash":81.9,"currentLength":294.4},{"offset":-294.4,"dash":66.3,"currentLength":360.7},{"offset":-360.7,"dash":61.4,"currentLength":422.1},{"offset":-422.1,"dash":76.5,"currentLength":498.6},{"offset":-498.6,"dash":116.9,"currentLength":615.5},{"offset":-615.5,"dash":89.3,"currentLength":704.8},{"offset":-704.8,"dash":90.2,"currentLength":795},{"offset":-795,"dash":26.6,"currentLength":821.6}]'>
  <path class="path" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" d="M66.039,133.545c0,0-21-57,18-67s49-4,65,8 s30,41,53,27s66,4,58,32s-5,44,18,57s22,46,0,
           45s-54-40-68-16s-40,88-83,48s11-61-11-80s-79-7-70-41 C46.039,146.545,53.039,128.545,66.039,133.545z"></path>
</svg>


<p>Animate single segment <button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, 0, 78.6)">1</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -78.6, 68.8)">2</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -147.4, 65.1)">3</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -212.5, 81.9)">4</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -294.4, 66.3)">5</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -360.7, 61.4)">6</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -422.1, 76.5)">7</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -498.6, 116.9)">8</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -615.5, 89.3)">9</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -704.8, 90.2)">10</button><button type="button" onclick="strokeTo(path,821.6, -795, 26.6)">11</button></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wish one didn't have to calculate the **length** of each path segment **manually**. I'm ok to use any different mode of animation too.

Comment: Unfortunately, segment lengths couldn't be retrieved directly (even getting all segments' commands still require some polyfills/helpers/libraries). For continuous stroke animations you could use the `pathLength` (super helpful for something like gauges) to get neat values - regardless of your actual path shape and length – won't work for segmented animations unless their segments have predictable lengths (due to their geometrical shape) like in my circle example (25 each). I've added an example, using data-attributes providing statically saved svgs with all segement data included.